# Aws iam command, Authenticate/validate User with username and password?

Tags: php, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

is there any **AWS IAM** command available through which we can authenticate or validate the user by passing his/her username & password combination?

eg: using this command

```
aws iam get-user --user-name test@domain.com
```

it returns

```
{
    "User": {
        "UserId": "AIDAJR3****VOYB2***NE",
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "test@domain.com",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::349578444322:user/test@domain.com",
        "CreateDate": "2015-12-07T15:46:20Z"
    }
}
```

what I want, I created a web APP, where user will enter his/her AWS username & password for login to the APP, So, is there any command or API available to validate/authenticate the user ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, I believe that's not possible.

> **Q: Is there an authentication API to verify user logins?**
>
> No. There is no programmatic way to verify user logins.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#login_anchor

AWS Management Console is the only application [+ Mobile Apps] which accepts the username & password combination to provide access to AWS Resources. All other routes involve IAM Role or IAM User or STS to get authenticated to access the AWS resources - **you cannot leverage or AWS to rely on authentication for your custom web applications**.

With that said, I can think of couple of alternatives, certainly not a solution you or work-around.

1. Sign-In using Amazon.com API http://login.amazon.com/manageApps
2. Using Amazon Cognito Authentication using different providers http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/authentication-flow/
3. Make use of Amazon Directory Services - Managed Active Directory. It is more like a Microsoft Active Directory as a Service, which you can make use to provide authentication for your custom web-application, while the uptime and health is taken care by AWS

Comment: I've added a link to the docs, confirming your answer that this isn't possible.  A moment's reflection suggests that such an API, if it existed, would be a horrible idea, anyway, because the system requesting the validation would be in possession of the password in cleartext.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Exactly, I certainly agree it would be a horrible idea. Thank you improving the answer

Comment: NaveenVijay & Michael Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run IE, or another browser simulator like selenium to programmatically log in. A sample powershell script to do that:

```
$account = "aws account name"
$username = "username";
$password = "somepassword";
$Url = "https://$account"+ ".signin.aws.amazon.com/console";



$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $false;
$ie.navigate($loginUrl);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; } 

#login
($ie.document.getElementsByName("account") | select -First 1).value = $account;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("username") |select -first 1).value = $username;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("password") |select -first 1).value = $password;
($ie.document.getElementsByClassName("css3button") |select -first 1).click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; }
```

So far this code won't tell us if the login was successful or not but you can build check and regex the page to get info. You can do a similar thing with JS, or C#